# How to get ID of img and then use that to change contents of DIV

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Ok, so I have a series of images that when clicked on will change the contents of a DIV with that image's ALT text. Here is the code for that-

```
$(function() {
  $('#dalton').click(function() {
    var alt = $(this).attr('alt');
    $('.article_desc').html(alt);
  });

  $('#rutherford').click(function() {
    var alt = $(this).attr('alt');
    $('.article_desc').html(alt);
  });

});
```

And I have this working just fine, but the issue is, if I have several images within the page, how can I optimize the code so I don't have to repeat it for each image?

I thought about setting a variable to the image ID-

```
$(function() {
$('img').click(function() {
var imgid = this.id;
```

But I don't know how to marry the two together.

EDIT: Here is the HTML for that section:

```html
<section class="section1">
    <article>
    <ul>
    <li><img src="plumpudding.gif" id="dalton" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"></li>
   <li><img src="rutherford.png" id="rutherford" alt="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit</li>
    <li><img src="bohr.gif" id="bohr" alt="Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi"></li>
    </ul> 
    <div class="clearfix"></div>  
    <div class="article_desc" id="article_desc">Click on the picture for description.</div>
    </article>
</section>
```

Comment: jquery each  function . ?

Comment: Just add a class to your image, and bind that click event on it

Comment: There are multiple ways to go about this. Can you post a sample of your HTML please?...

Comment: Edited post with HTML of that section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making a named function could be helpful here.

```
$(function () {
    $("#dalton").click(setDescriptionToAlt);
    $('#rutherford').click(setDescriptionToAlt);

    // OR use a class given to each element.

    $(".image-with-alt").click(setDescriptionToAlt);
});

function setDescriptionToAlt() {
    var alt = $(this).attr("alt");
    $(".article_desc").html(alt);
}
```

By having a named function you just need to reference it instead of copying the inline anonymous function every time. From there you can decide to do a click event for each element id you need or you could assign a class to each element to be affected and use that instead.

Comment: Thank you! I gave each img a class of "image-with-alt" and replaced the script with what you gave and it's wonderful! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try this....So that you can get all clicked image `alt` information.Note that all `img` tags must have `class='image'` and define the id for text area `id= 'article_desc'` where you want to display `alt` information.

```
$('.image').click(function() {
    var alt = $(this).attr('alt');
    $('#article_desc').append(alt);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Instead of id's of elements use class name

```
$('.image').click(function() {
    var alt = $(this).attr('alt');
    $('.article_desc').html(alt);
});
```

Comment: an explanation would be useful?